# ActionBar (Support) with Fragment (support)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment

I need to use a combination of action bar and fragments in one of my android applications that targets Gingerbread too. So I have used the action bar from the v7 support library and fragments from the v4 support library and extend my class with FragmentActivity.

I get an error when I type out the line

```
actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
```

The error states that **getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type myFragmentClass** (my class name). The code works perfectly without the support library. Is there a solution to my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have imported the right library? android.support.v7.app.ActionBar

Comment: I did. I Got the action bar to work as well. The problem came about when I tried to include the fragment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You must extend ActionBarActivity instead of FragmentActivity to have Actionbar with fragments.

If you're using the v7 appcompat library, your activity should instead extend ActionBarActivity, which is a subclass of FragmentActivity (for more information, read Adding the Action Bar).

You can find more info at the page given below.The above line is taken from the page below(Last para).
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Edit- This is not a bug. Its just lack of knowledge. Sometimes basic are not clear. I am currently learning, that too from the android website, and that's how I got to give you the answer.

Comment: Yes I got it working after a few days, by extending ActionBarActivity. Just forgot to update my post. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 45):

write this code in OnAttach() method:

```
actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
```

ActionBarActivity is deprecated. Use

`actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will try it the next time. I've moved on to use action bar since..

Comment: ActionBarActivity is deprecated. Use `((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();` instead.

Answer (score 8):

I had also tried using:

```
actionbar = getActivity().getSupportActionBar();
```

and it didn't work until I did this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
```

So it worked when I cast to my MainActivity.

Comment: Don't use this method as fragments are designed to be reused in multiple activities and if you use the fragment in a different activity other than "MainActivity" it will crash. Bhr's answer of casting to the super class ActionBarActivity is correct.

Comment: Correct. I did not have that knowledge then.

Answer (score 8):

for **android.support.v7**

```
ActionBar actionBar =  ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();

//than next for example 
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

To call the ActionBar inside a Fragment use this:

```
actionbar = getActivity().getSupportActionBar();
```

A Fragment has no ActionBar but the Activity. That's why you have to call it this way.

Comment: I cant get the getActivity() option in eclipse

Comment: This has nothing to do with eclipse. Be sure to call this line in a Fragment.

Comment: The method getActivity() is undefined for the class: That is the error I get when I added the code.

Comment: This has to be a bug, hasn't it? I've been trying this for 2 days now!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it by extending ActionBarActivity and make some changes in AndroidManifest.xml
as

```
 <activity android:name="yourActionbarActivity"
```

android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

and it works fine for me

Answer (score -3):

No need to do any changes any where, just use
`getActionBar().setTitle(title)` instead of `getSupportActionBar` when you use `FragmentActivity`. It's working fine for me.

Comment: It wont work on all devices. You need getSupportActionBar() to support devices below API 11.