# Hide/show arrow/menu on toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar

So, i have Activity with FrameLayout, code of activity layout

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
     android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
     app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>
```

and when i'm going to differents fragment i need to change toolbar.

I need to set different text, show back arrow, remove back arrow, and show/remove three dots in right corner for menu.

I have next code in Activity

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ...
    }
```

and next methods in my class

```
public void setTextTabBar(String title) {
    getSupportActionBar().show();
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}

public void setTabBarFragment() {
    getSupportActionBar().show();
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.about_app_title));
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setFragment(fragmentMain);
        }
    });
}
```

Is this right way? I'm coding to android 8+.

Also i need to add menu, and remove back arrow, how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, assuming your fragment transaction is replacing the `<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>` part of your code. According to this post: [ActionBar (Support) with Fragment (support)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052470/actionbar-support-with-fragment-support)
You need to extend each fragment so they can have their own action bars.

This makes sense as fragments are supposed to be modular in nature and only call back to the host activity when you implement special functions, callbacks, or listeners to do so.

As far as your back arrows go, you will need the code lines: `getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` to enable and set the back button. And just change the booleans to false if removing the back arrow.

Comment: `getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`  does not work

Comment: @Waldmann, when you say doesn't work, do you mean that you set it in your activity and the functionality didn't change? Or do you mean that you tried to set it in the fragment and AS couldn't resolve it?